# What has to do the h2 in memory database with the local machine? Does it persist something on the local machine?

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, h2, in-memory-database

**Context:**
1. So I have project "x" based on java and local machine (a laptop) "a" with linux.
2. Project "x" is used by a lot of teams with exactly the same laptop and operating system.

**Situation:**
1. The project worked like a charm until point "t". I have made no modifications to the project or to local machine before and in point "t".
2. I clone project "x" (from git) on local machine "a".
3. From terminal I run a script "./gradlew test" for the project "x"

**Problem:**
1. From all the teams only on my local machine "a" I have the following test failed:

```
xxx.webservice.ProductMigrationTaskMapperTest > testContextIsMappedCorrectly FAILED
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "MIGRATION_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO CUST_JOB_TASK (CUST_JOB_TASK_NO, GUID, ITEMS_FAILED, ITEMS_SUCCESSFUL, ITEMS_TOTAL, LIFECYCLE_STATUS, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_LANGUAGE_ID, MIGRATION_DATE, OPT_LOCK, EXECUTION_DATE, RESP_AUTHOR_NO, SOURCE_CUSTOMER_NO, TARGET_CUSTOMER_NO, TYPE, DATEI, DATEW, USERI, USERW, TASK_CANCELLED_AT, TASK_CANCELLED_BY, 
TASK_CREATED_AT, TASK_PROCESSED_AT, TASK_STARTED_AT, LOG_EMAIL, ADD_CUST_ORDER_NO, DEL_CUST_ORDER_NO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-193]
    Error Code: 42122
    Call: INSERT INTO CUST_JOB_TASK (CUST_JOB_TASK_NO, GUID, ITEMS_FAILED, ITEMS_SUCCESSFUL, ITEMS_TOTAL, LIFECYCLE_STATUS, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_LANGUAGE_ID, MIGRATION_DATE, OPT_LOCK, EXECUTION_DATE, RESP_AUTHOR_NO, SOURCE_CUSTOMER_NO, TARGET_CUSTOMER_NO, TYPE, DATEI, DATEW, USERI, USERW, TASK_CANCELLED_AT, TASK_CANCELLE
D_BY, TASK_CREATED_AT, TASK_PROCESSED_AT, TASK_STARTED_AT, LOG_EMAIL, ADD_CUST_ORDER_NO, DEL_CUST_ORDER_NO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [27 parameters bound]
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(ProductMigrationTaskEntity 67)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:879)
        at yyy.insertBatch(EntityList.java:136)
        at yyy.EntityList.insertEntitiesImpl(EntityList.java:86)
        at yyy.EntityList.insertEntities(EntityList.java:73)
        at yyy.EmbeddedPersistenceTestCase.insertRememberedEntities(EmbeddedPersistenceTestCase.java:178)
        at zzz.productmigration.construction.webservice.ProductMigrationTaskMapperTest.executeMapping(ProductMigrationTaskMapperTest.java:262)
        at rrr.productmigration.construction.webservice.ProductMigrationTaskMapperTest.testContextIsMappedCorrectly(ProductMigrationTaskMapperTest.java:220)

        Caused by:
        Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
        Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "MIGRATION_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
        INSERT INTO CUST_JOB_TASK (CUST_JOB_TASK_NO, GUID, ITEMS_FAILED, ITEMS_SUCCESSFUL, ITEMS_TOTAL, LIFECYCLE_STATUS, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_LANGUAGE_ID, MIGRATION_DATE, OPT_LOCK, EXECUTION_DATE, RESP_AUTHOR_NO, SOURCE_CUSTOMER_NO, TARGET_CUSTOMER_NO, TYPE, DATEI, DATEW, USERI, USERW, TASK_CANCELLED_AT, TASK_CANCELLED_
BY, TASK_CREATED_AT, TASK_PROCESSED_AT, TASK_STARTED_AT, LOG_EMAIL, ADD_CUST_ORDER_NO, DEL_CUST_ORDER_NO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-193]
        Error Code: 42122
        Call: INSERT INTO CUST_JOB_TASK (CUST_JOB_TASK_NO, GUID, ITEMS_FAILED, ITEMS_SUCCESSFUL, ITEMS_TOTAL, LIFECYCLE_STATUS, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_LANGUAGE_ID, MIGRATION_DATE, OPT_LOCK, EXECUTION_DATE, RESP_AUTHOR_NO, SOURCE_CUSTOMER_NO, TARGET_CUSTOMER_NO, TYPE, DATEI, DATEW, USERI, USERW, TASK_CANCELLED_AT, TASK_CANC
ELLED_BY, TASK_CREATED_AT, TASK_PROCESSED_AT, TASK_STARTED_AT, LOG_EMAIL, ADD_CUST_ORDER_NO, DEL_CUST_ORDER_NO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                bind => [27 parameters bound]
        Query: InsertObjectQuery(ProductMigrationTaskEntity 67)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2056)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1790)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:227)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:194)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:139)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4264)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
            ... 6 more

            Caused by:
            org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "MIGRATION_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
            INSERT INTO CUST_JOB_TASK (CUST_JOB_TASK_NO, GUID, ITEMS_FAILED, ITEMS_SUCCESSFUL, ITEMS_TOTAL, LIFECYCLE_STATUS, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_LANGUAGE_ID, MIGRATION_DATE, OPT_LOCK, EXECUTION_DATE, RESP_AUTHOR_NO, SOURCE_CUSTOMER_NO, TARGET_CUSTOMER_NO, TYPE, DATEI, DATEW, USERI, USERW, TASK_CANCELLED_AT, TASK_CANCEL
LED_BY, TASK_CREATED_AT, TASK_PROCESSED_AT, TASK_STARTED_AT, LOG_EMAIL, ADD_CUST_ORDER_NO, DEL_CUST_ORDER_NO) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-193]
                at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
                at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
                at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
                at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:682)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:878)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:862)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1062)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:413)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:317)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:289)
                at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:254)
                at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:561)
                at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:502)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1203)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
                at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:287)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
                at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
                ... 35 more
```

**What I have already tried:**

1. Delete entire project, get it fresh from git, run tests. Got same error.
2. Removed ~/.m2; ~/.gradle
3. Removed everything in /tmp
4. Changed java version to java version "1.8.0_152"

**NOTES:**
1. Because only on my computer the tests don't work I assume it is a local problem
2. Because of point 1, I don't see relevant do give a lot of details about the project "x"

Comment: What makes you think that this column *is* defined?

Comment: The fact is that I assume that that column is not created in the h2 database. But why on earth to all the developers it is created when they clone the project and on my exact same local machine it is probably not created...?

Comment: You would need to ask these other developers.  As is currently written, the best we can do is speculate, which will not be helpful to you at all.

Comment: Well I have asked for 3 days and no one can figure it out. The last solution that I see is to reinstall linux (which is a crappy solution). I am trying to figure it out if the h2 db has something to do with the local machine. Someting that I am missing.

Comment: What's your connection string?